# How to smoothly translate view in iMessage extension in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-extensions

I have issue when I try to push view controller in `willTransitionToPresentationStyle:`. The view was blinking for a split second before it fully expanded.  It might be a small glitch or bug since iOS 10 and Xcode 8 are still in beta. But when I manually requested to change presentation style to `MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded` by calling `requestPresentationStyle:` after I push view controller, it went to expand mode more smoothly. Does anyone have similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problems with transitions in iMessage apps. I think this should improve considerably when iOS 10 and Xcode 8 come out of beta, but for now we have to deal with Xcode's bugs.

There's a few things I've done to make this look better. Inside my extension I have a method that checks the presentation style every time the view changes. This method manages two different UIs - one for `MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded` and one for `MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact`. This method hides and shows specific views accordingly. In my compact UI I have a button that allows the user to expand the interface by clicking it (this is basically the same as clicking the up arrow at the bottom right of the screen).

I've noticed that if you let the user expand the messages app after the view has been loaded for a while the transitions are *much* smoother and less buggy. Not sure why this is the case, but you should give it a try. Also, I've found segues to be extremely buggy, so that's why I went with keeping everything on one view controller.

Comment: oh well, good thing is i don't use segues xD.. Xcode has been crashed like  1000 times today ugh..